# Is object oriented programming ALWAYS a good way for large projects?

Tags: design

Is object oriented programming always the good way for all types of projects? Is this methodology the best suited for large projects like compilers, interpreters and other large systems? Most of the compilers are written in C so I can't see any compilers written in the object oriented method. I think OOP benefits the most in places like LOB, simulations where you can consider everything as an object. But is it really useful in all places? Also OOP can lead to inefficient code than procedural code. Not to mention that design patterns sometimes increase the complexity of design.

Comment: Since version 4.8 GCC is written in C++.

Comment: You can implement an object-oriented design in a procedural language like C. Regarding your question: there are programmers that are not convinced OOP is a better choice for _any_ project, and prefer to use some other paradigm.

Comment: @Giorgio: Yes, it is possible, but is it common?

Comment: @Fish: yes, e.g. functional programmers will not use OOP, unless they choose a hybrid functional-OO language like Scala in which you can combine the two paradigms.

Comment: @Giorgio Depends on your definition of OOP. An object is just a record of functions, so there's nothing stopping you from using them in a functional language. What you probably won't find is inheritance and mutation.

Comment: @Doval: You can see an object as a function that given a method name returns a function (the method implementation), i.e. an object is a higher-order function implementing dynamic dispatching. However, nobody forces you to use this pattern when using functional programming.

Comment: **[Unclear what help you need](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important "see: 'Why is research important?'").** Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell what problem you are trying to solve or what aspect of your approach needs to be corrected or explained. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @Giorgio In my opinion you're conflating objects with dynamic dispatch. At any rate, nobody forces you to use it in OOP languages either. Any time you have a `final class` with no public subclasses or superclasses, that's an abstract data type, not an object. Unless you only use `interface`s, you're not using *only* objects.

Comment: A compiler is not such a large project.

Comment: @Doval: I may be wrong. I found some interesting ideas in SICP. If I understand it correctly, a distinguishing feature of object-oriented programming is the use of message passing (dynamic dispatch) instead of dispatching on type using `if (x instanceof ...)` like in Java or using pattern-matching like in FP (see http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-17.html#%_sec_2.4.3). A second distinguishing feature (see http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-19.html), is the use of state, which OO has in common with procedural programming: both are imperative paradigms.

Comment: @Giorgio Which is why I say it depends on your definition of OOP. Everyone has their own definition for the *paradigm*. But an *object* is just [a record of functions](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~wcook/Drafts/2009/essay.pdf). If you consider OOP to be "programming with objects", you can do that in any functional language. If you consider mutation to be an integral part of OOP, then you'd be right. If you consider OOP to be [message passing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing) then you're probably a Smalltalk fan.

Comment: @Doval: Well, even if there are many different definitions of OOP, I was trying to identify the features that are common to all these definitions. IMO these are dynamic dispatch / message passing (which you also have outside of Smalltalk) and state. I consider state and mutation as an integral part of OOP because without mutation you lose the idea of object identity (the same object can have different states, two objects with the same attributes may still have a different identity). Also, OOP is imperative: there is no imperative programming without state. Again, I may be wrong.

Comment: @m3th0dman are sure about that? Have a look to the codebase of GCC or Clang and think again :) speaking of which, both are written in C++, Clang even in C++11.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lets try to understand why OOP became popular. It is because of the maintainability problem. Any large codebase has to be just as maintainable as small codebase. Since, OOP features decoupling, modularity, reuse, etc., it helps developing maintainable code. Also, nowadays performance issues are often neglected in favor of maintainability because with advanced algorithms and faster hardware, performance issues can be limited to an acceptable level.

However, there are projects for which different programming paradigms are preferred. Primarily because these projects have different goals. For instance, functional reactive programming have come to fashion for event-based and asynchronous systems development.

So, to answer your question, OOP is the most popular programming paradigm in use now. OOP programmers often times, either out of enthusiasm or ignorance, try to apply it to develop solutions that should be developed using other paradigms.

Comment: "Since, OOP features decoupling, modularity, reuse, etc., it helps developing maintainable code.": All these features are available in procedural and in functional languages, so they are not OOP-specific.

Comment: Thats correct even for procedural programming! However, OOP actively encourages these features and have established them in mainstream development.

Comment: "OOP features decoupling, modularity, reuse, etc., it helps developing maintainable code" - Hmmm yeah, but if the programmers are not doing it right, it doesn't matter.  And in my experience, most are not doing it right.  (Just making a remark, not criticizing the answer... ;))

Comment: That is correct. The primary reason I would say is that the ivory tower OOP masters have failed us by documenting OOP which read like journal papers! Think about the time investment of a typical OOP developer to learn it!